# Word for a retailer's distinctive products

Tags: terminology, business-language

When I worked in retail, I learned terms such as "loss leader", which describes a product that generates little or no profit but draws customers into a store.

Is there a similar term for the *unique* products, among a retailer's many less distinctive ones, which draw customers to the store?

For example: I shop at Trader Joe's primarily for their cheese selection.  I buy a lot of other things while I'm there, but I would seldom shop there at all if not for the cheese.  Another example: I used to shop at Target primarily for a specific brand of baby wipes.  Since those wipes have been discontinued, I'm far less likely to shop at Target.

What are these kinds of products called?

Comment: I don't know about retail, but in general sales, particularly B2B, these are known as *differentiators*.

Comment: @DanBron Could you post that as an answer?

Comment: @DanBron Your comment is the best match for the intent of my question.  Could you post it as an answer?

Comment: If you like. Gimme 10 minutes.

Comment: Sometimes "flagship" is used with this meaning.

Answer (score 3):

The word **[exclusive](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/exclusive)** is often used in this context.

> Not divided or shared with others: *exclusive publishing rights*.

As an example:

[To Stand Out, Retailers Flock to Exclusive Lines](http://www.nytimes.com/2011/02/15/business/15retail.html?_r=0)

> ...stores are increasingly relying on merchandise that can be found
>   nowhere else. Retailers can mark these **exclusive** lines down at their
>   own pace, with a far more profitable outcome than with a national
>   brand.

Answer (score 0):

I would call them **"quality products"**.

to be considered a quality product, it has to offer the best quality you can find in your area, in addition to a reasonable price. And **how exactly can we define quality** in this context, a product that attracts you to a certain shop?

Basically it refers to **how much the product exceeds your expectations**.

> - ["quality"](http://encyclopedia2.thefreedictionary.com/Product+quality) -  The collection of features and characteristics of a product that contribute to its ability to meet given requirements.

Answer (score 0):

In sales, particularly "enterprise" or business-to-business (B2B) sales, such characteristics are known as *product **differentiators***.

From Wikipedia's article on *product differentiation*, for example:

> In economics and marketing, *product differentiation* (or simply differentiation) is the process of distinguishing a product or service from others, to make it more attractive to a particular target market.
>
> This involves differentiating it from competitors' products as well as a firm's own products. The concept was proposed by Edward Chamberlin in his 1933 Theory of Monopolistic Competition.